# Wrong output code in java in Java IF statements for a simple game

Tags: java, if-statement, output

I have to make a rock paper scissors game that includes multiple classes and methods.
One of the classes is to establish the Computer player which is supposed to generate a random choice and then see if it won against (`didIWin` method) the player's choice. I tested the computer's random choice against the player's choice of rock, paper, and scissors which would tell you if your method is working right.
My output is giving me the same answer for all three and I have no clue what I am doing wrong. It has to be in the `didIWin` method, I think. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
    public class Computer
    {
    //instance / member variables
    private String choice;
    private int choiceNumber;

    public Computer()
    {
        //call random set Choice
        randomSetChoice();
    }

    public String getChoice()
    {
        return "" + choice;
    }

    public void randomSetChoice()
    {
        //use Math.random()
        int min = 1;
        int max = 4;
        choiceNumber = (int)(Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min));

        //use switch case
        switch(choiceNumber)
        {
            case 1: choice =  "rock"; break; 
            case 2: choice =  "paper"; break;
            case 3: choice = "scissors"; break;
            default: choice = "invalid input...try again"; 
        }
    }   

    /*
    didIWin(Player p) will return the following values
    0 - both players have the same choice
    1 - the computer had the higher ranking choice
    -1 - the player had the higher ranking choice
     */ 
    public int didIWin(Player p)
    {
        String pc = p.getChoice();
        if(choice == "rock")
        {
            if(pc == "rock")
            {
                return 0; 
            }
            else if(pc == "paper")
            {
                return -1;
            }
            else
            {
                return 1; 
            }
        }

        else if(choice == "paper")
        {
            if(pc == "paper")
            {
                return 0;
            }
            else if(pc == "scissors")
            {
                return -1;
            }
            else
            {
                return 1;
            }
        }
        
        else
        {
            if(pc == "scissors")
            {
                return 0;
            }
            else if(pc == "rock")
            {
                return -1;
            }
            else
            {
                return 1;
            }     
        }
         
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return "" + "Computer chose " + choice + "!";
    }          
    }
```

Comment: It's best to compare strings with equals() rather than ==. == only works if the two strings refer to the same object. Equals works if the strings have the same characters in the same order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, if you test the method `didWin()` it works!

I tried with this simple example:

```java
    public class Main {
        static private String str = "scissors";
        static private String choice = "paper";
        static int didWin(){
            String pc = str;
            if(choice == "rock"){
                if(pc == "rock"){
                    return 0; 
                }
                else if(pc == "paper"){
                    return -1;
                }
                else{
                    return 1; 
                }
            }
            else if(choice == "paper"){
                if(pc == "paper"){
                    return 0;
                }
                else if(pc == "scissors"){
                    return -1;
                }
                else{
                    return 1;
                }
            }
            else {
                if(pc == "scissors"){
                    return 0;
                }
                else if(pc == "rock"){
                    return -1;
                }
                else {
                    return 1;
                }     
            }
     
        }
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println(didWin());
        }
    }
```

All the tries worked.

Notice that you wrote `didIWin()` and not `didWin()` in the question, so maybe **this can be the issue**.

Maybe you can edit with the `Player` class and some of your tries.

Comment: I test didIWin against rock, paper, and scissors and no matter what the computer's choice is, it will not print out -1. I use equals() now and 0 works, so thank you! It is just -1.

Comment: I used equals() on all of them and it finally worked! thank yall!